# React JavaScript prevent component unmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, jsx

I'm new to React JavaScript. Previously I'm a desktop app developer with WPF and I uses `Frame` and `Page` extensively for my desktop apps. I want to achieve almost the same thing with React JavaScript. I want to make a bottom tab bar with React JavaScript. Here is my current work:

`App.js`:

```
import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BottomTabBar from './BottomTabBar/BottomTabBar';
import HomePage from './HomePage/HomePage';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let menuItems = [];

    menuItems.push({
      label: 'Home',
      faIcon: 'fas fa-home',
      content: (
        <HomePage/>
      )
    });

    menuItems.push({
      label: 'Numbers',
      faIcon: 'fas fa-ellipsis-h',
      content: (
        <h1>
          This is numbers page.
        </h1>
      )
    });

    menuItems.push({
      label: 'Notifications',
      faIcon: 'fas fa-bell',
      content: (
        <h1>
          This is notifications page.
        </h1>
      )
    });

    menuItems.push({
      label: 'Menu',
      faIcon: 'fas fa-bars',
      content: (
        <h1>
          This is menu page.
        </h1>
      )
    });

    return (
      <div 
        className='App'
      >
        <BottomTabBar
          menuItems={menuItems}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`BottomTabBar.js`:

```
import './BottomTabBar.css';
import '../Ripple.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class BottomTabBar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      content: null,
      selectedTabIndex: 0,
    };
  }

  handleClick = (index) => {
    // Changing content.
    this.setState({
      selectedTabIndex: index
    });
  }

  render() {
    // Putting them all.
    return (
      <div
        className='BottomTabBar'
      >
        <div
          className='Content'
        >
          {this.props.menuItems[this.state.selectedTabIndex].content}
        </div>

        <div
          className='IconsBar'
        >
          {
            this.props.menuItems.map((menuItem, i) => {
              return (
                <div
                  className="MenuItem Ripple"
                  key={i}
                  onClick={()=>this.handleClick(i)}
                >
                  <div
                    className="Gap"
                  />
                  <div
                    className="Icon"
                  >
                    <div
                      className={menuItem.faIcon}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div
                    className="Gap"
                  />
                  <div
                    className="Text"
                  >
                    {menuItem.label}
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            })
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BottomTabBar;
```

`HomePage.js`:

```
import './HomePage.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class HomePage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      counter: 0,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.counterInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        counter: prevState.counter + 1
      }));
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.counterInterval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className='HomePage'
      >
        Home page counter: {this.state.counter}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HomePage;
```

As you might know from the codes above, my homepage is just a simple page with automatic counter increment per second:

Normal home page:
[image: Normal home page]

The problem is my `HomePage` can't be persistent. If I tried to change between tabs, it works but the counter at the home page is always reset to 0, meaning my home page and the other pages are recreated just because it is navigated between tabs. That's very weird to me as I created the `<HomePage/>` at the `App.js` line 14. What I'm doing wrong? Feel free to ask me if you need more details.

Maybe what I'm trying to do is more like this library:

https://github.com/lishengzxc/react-no-unmount-hide

I'm not really sure what that library does but I tried it and it doesn't work (just throws some weird error)

Comment: All relevant code should be presented in question body. External links may become broken. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Im sorry but it seems that all the codes above are all relevant to my problem so i dont think pasting them all here is a good idea

Comment: It's a good idea. This is required by SO rules, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , *Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.
    If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.*

Comment: i have discarded the links for code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for hours, i finally managed to do it based on my idea. Here is the code for those who curious:

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BottomTabBar from './BottomTabBar/BottomTabBar';
import HomePage from './HomePage/HomePage';
import NumbersPage from './NumbersPage/NumbersPage';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let menuItems = [];

    menuItems.push({
      label: 'Home',
      faIcon: 'fas fa-home'
    });

    menuItems.push({
      label: 'Numbers',
      faIcon: 'fas fa-ellipsis-h'
    });

    return (
      <div 
        className='App'
      >
        <BottomTabBar
          menuItems={menuItems}
        >
          <HomePage/>
          <NumbersPage/>
        </BottomTabBar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

BottomTabBar.js:

```
import './BottomTabBar.css';
import '../Ripple.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class BottomTabBar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      selectedIndex: 0,
    };

    console.log('Initialized bottom tab bar');
  }

  handleClick = (index) => {
    // Changing content.
    this.setState({
      selectedIndex: index
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className='BottomTabBar'
      >
        <div
          className='Content'
        >
          {
            this.props.children.map((child, i) => {
              return (
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: i == this.state.selectedIndex
                    ? 'block'
                    : 'none'
                  }}
                  key={i}
                >
                  {child}
                </div>
              )
            })
          }
        </div>

        <div
          className='IconsBar'
        >
          {
            this.props.menuItems.map((menuItem, i) => {
              return (
                <div
                  className="MenuItem Ripple"
                  key={i}
                  onClick={()=>this.handleClick(i)}
                >
                  <div
                    className="Gap"
                  />
                  <div
                    className="Icon"
                  >
                    <div
                      className={menuItem.faIcon}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div
                    className="Gap"
                  />
                  <div
                    className="Text"
                  >
                    {menuItem.label}
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            })
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BottomTabBar;
```

HomePage.js:

```
import './HomePage.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class HomePage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      counter: 0,
    };

    console.log('Initialized home page');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.counterInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        counter: prevState.counter + 1
      }));
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.counterInterval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className='HomePage'
        style={this.props.style}
      >
        Home page counter: {this.state.counter}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HomePage;
```

Note: NumbersPage.js is just basically a page with very long lorem ipsum text.

Thats it, all states preserved without lifting. The scrolling position on NumbersPage.js is not preserved because i played with css display property there and thats normal :)

Thanks for the helps!

Answer (score 1):

It's expected because new `HomePage` instance is created each time *Home* tab is navigated.

This is the case for [lifting the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). If counter state should persist, it should be moved to a component that isn't destroyed on tab navigation, i.e. `App`:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { counter: 0 };

  incrementCounter = () => setState((state) => ({ counter: state.counter + 1 }));

  render() {
    let menuItems = [];

    menuItems.push({
      label: 'Home',
      faIcon: 'fas fa-home',
      content: (
        <HomePage counter={this.state.counter} increment={this.incrementCounter} />
      )
    });
    ...
```

These props should be used instead of local `HomePage` state:

```
this.counterInterval = setInterval(this.props.increment);
```

and

```
Home page counter: {this.props.counter}
```

An alternative is to use Redux or React context API to manage global application state.

Comment: but will it be efficient? i mean just changing the counter and the whole HomePage is recreated (CMIIW)

Comment: what abt the youtube-tab like case? i mean when you have a very long list, i dont want to reset that list from the beginning again just because you are changing the tabs.

Comment: No, the solution is not very efficient. It explains why this happens and how the state can be lifted up. Context API (with some modifications, i.e. `menuItems` shouldn't be redeclared on each render) or Redux would be more efficient, both performance and design-wise.

Comment: the idea is to load all 4 pages into the app only once and show only 1 page content based on selected tab so it will retain the states for each pages without even lifting or care abt the other ui components (like scrolling position, etc)

Comment: The principle is uniform for any components that act like that. If the state needs to be preserved when it should be lifted, as described here https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html . There may be other ways like storing native element references and hiding/showing them instead of re-rendering, but it's less straightforward in React. I'd suggest to go with Redux or other state management library, the app could already benefit from it.

Comment: Regarding 'without even lifting', what if you will need to rerender the app any way? E.g. change language or horizontal/vertical layout. All UI will reset, scrolling positions, etc. if you don't store them.

Comment: u dont change the app language as often as switching tabs and horizontal and vertical layout will just basically change the width and height of the app (i tried that in cordova with jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the react-router-dom components for Linking and Navigation purposes.

This Project is based on something you want to achieve. Check it out

https://github.com/onejeet/image-sharing-app

Comment: yea, i have tried that too but my case is this is actually for my cordova app so i want to make almost true mobile experience. the example is tabs on youtube app. it is persistent when you change tabs. i also have made the working app but with just jquery and it is a total mess now so i decided to use reactjs. (please dont suggest me to use react native because i want to learn reactjs for now).

Comment: the idea is hide all tabs u dont want to see and only show the content of selected one. the problem is just the pages will be recreated and replaced...

Comment: the Routers in reactjs will help you achieve this. the links to the different components without giving a refresh to the page, which ultimately retains your state.